# Multi-user Google Webmaster Tools API

Tags: api, google-analytics, google-api, google-search-console

I'm attempting to create a tool for use by a group of Google Apps users to automate the creation of Google Analytics and Webmaster Tools accounts for a list of domains.

I use OAuth for signing in, and can successfully get a list of Analytics Properties and Webmaster Tools properties for the signed in account. I can also create a Webmaster Tools property from the API and verify the site using the Site Verification API.

Google Analytics is multi-user - simply add a user to the account and the Analytics API call (analytics.management.accountSummaries.list) for that user will now return the account as being in their list, complete with all properties within that account.

The problem is this:
**Google Webmaster Tools behaves differently**.

It seems multiple users cannot manage a shared Google Webmaster Tools account in the same way. The only option I am able to find is to add additional users to each **property** within the Webmaster Tools account.

This means that in my application, each user will need to create and verify the same domains in order to view them in their account. This will lead to mismanagement and significant duplication of efforts.

Is it possible to "group manage" a list of Google Webmaster Tools properties the same way Google Analytics does (without adding each user to each property)?